# with ocr is it possible to making a clickable button in a image?

Tags: node.js, vue.js, vuetify.js, ocr

[image: this is the example i'm trying to do]

I want to do an example for daily test
user will upload images then it can be mark question answers
after that another one can be resolve that test with clickable buttons
thanks in advance I am working on this examples for weeks and I cant find any result

Comment: I would suggest learning more about image processing. This would be really complex to implement, and most likely would need to be done on the backend first, with the ocr result passed to the front end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Totally possible with just a javascript library. Checking out [tesseract](https://tesseract.projectnaptha.com/), it seems to put boxes around the words it finds, from there it's just a matter of adding an @click function to them. Otherwise you can make your own <button> tags with absolute position and width computed by the results of its api.

So yes it's very possible.